# Continuity in $\mathcal{C}([0,1])$ under $L^2$ norm

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity, normed-spaces

I need to prove (or show a counterexample) that the following function:
$$ \begin{array}{rcl}
F: \mathcal{C}([0,1]) & \rightarrow & \mathbb{R} \\
x & \mapsto & \int_0^1 x(t)\ dt
\end{array}$$
is continuous relative to the $L^2$ norm on $\mathcal{C}([0,1])$, which is:
$$\lVert x \rVert_2=\sqrt{\int_0^1|x(t)|^2 \ dt}$$

In case it is continuous, I know it would suffice to show that the $L^2 $ norm somehow bounds the $L^1$ norm from above, since:
$$\bigg|\int_0^1 x(t) \ dt -\int_0^1 \overline{x}(t) \ dx \bigg|\leq\int_0^1|x(t)-\overline{x}(t)| \ dt = \lVert x-\overline{x}\rVert_1$$

Otherwise, I would have to find an example of a sequence of functions $(x_n)_n$ that converges to some point $\overline{x}$ such that $\int_0^1 x_n(t) \ dt$ does not converge to $\int_0^1 \overline{x}(t) \ dt$. Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you know Holder's inequality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can prove that $F$ is continuous using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality\begin{align}|F(x)|&=\left|\int_0^1x(t)\,\mathrm dt\right|\\&=\left|\int_0^1x(t)\times1\,\mathrm dt\right|\\&\leqslant\sqrt{\int_0^1x^2(t)\,\mathrm dt}\sqrt{\int_0^11^2\,\mathrm dt}\\&=\|x\|.\end{align}